# Eloquent is saving no values in not null fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, migration

I'm making a migration and I want some fields to be not nullable. To make easier I will use the users migration that comes with Laravel as an example.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

None of its fields are nullables but if I make:

```
$user = new User();
$user->save();
User::all();
```

It returns

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#639
     all: [
       App\User {#640
         id: "1",
         name: "",
         email: "",
         created_at: "2016-06-29 15:51:01",
         updated_at: "2016-06-29 15:51:01",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Where is the point of the nullable() modifier if I can save records without data in not null fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, they're empty but they aren't null - as expected. To avoid empty entries you must use validation rules to enforce that:

In a controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|min:4',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
    ]);

    $user = User::create($request->only('name', 'email', 'password'));

    return redirect()->route('users.show', $user->id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `VARCHAR` field have default value as "". `string` of the `Blueprint $table` generate `varchar` [column](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-columns).

If you want set no nullable columns use `->nullable(false)`

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->nullable(false);
    $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable(false);
    $table->string('password')->nullable(false);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this situation put these lines in the file /config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    ...
    'modes' => [
        'STRICT_ALL_TABLES',
    ],
],
```